# Sort Realm results by case insensitive property

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm sorting my results by a property called "alphabet" like this:

```
allArtists = Artist.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingProperty("alphabet", ascending: true)
```

How can I sort with case insensitive? Right now "cop" will appear before "Cat".

Comment: that isn't supported by realm, you will need to do that custom. The best way is probably similar to what Velthune described, so you will be building a new NSArray that is sorted properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you have to write your custom compare method:

```
sortedArray = [array ArrayUsingSelector:@selector(customCompare:)];
```

Where customCompare is a method of your object:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)customCompare:(NSString*)string {
    return [[string lowercaseString] compare:[self.string lowercaseString]];
}
```

In your case is simply:

```
sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to retain the benefits of using a `RLMResults` object, another way to do this is to add a case-insensitive copy of the property on your model:

```
class Artist: RLMObject {
    /// Some original property you want to sort by
    dynamic var name = "" {
        didSet {
            // Keep the case-free property in sync 
            lowercaseName = name.lowercaseString
        }
    }

    /// A new property just for case-insensitive sorting
    dynamic var lowercaseName = ""
}
```

Then you can sort on the new property instead:

```
let caseInsensitiveArtists = Artist.allObjects()
    .sortedResultsUsingProperty("lowercaseName", ascending: true)
```